# Langchain - get list of names from my documents

Tags: openai-api, langchain, gpt-3, large-language-model, palm

I have more than 500 documents. Some of them have person names in it. I want to extract all names from all documents. I indexed documents using ChromaDB. I tried PlanAndExecute and and Self-ask with search agents but they could not provide a correct answer.

https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/agent_types/self_ask_with_search

https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/agent_types/plan_and_execute

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: to debug, add a code you tried along with some sample input and the incorrect answer it provided.